# Typescript - How can I conditionally define a type based on another property

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to conditionally set the return type of a function, based on a static value in the same type.

Given the following code, is it possible to have type checking work as I've specified in the comments?

**IE**, if `const taskX: Task` has the `id: 'get-name'`, how can I make it so `taskX.run()` should return according to the type defined as `Outputs['get-name']`

```js
type Outputs = {
  "get-name": {
    name: string;
  };
  "get-age": {
    age: number;
  };
  "get-favourite-fruits": ("apple" | "strawberry" | "melon")[];
};

type Task = {
  // This should always be a static property defined in `Outputs`
  id: keyof Outputs;
  // How can I make this conditional and return the type from `Outputs` based on `id`
  run: () => never; 
};

const taskOne: Task = {
  id: "get-name",
  // This should be valid
  run: () => {
    return { name: "frankenstein" };
  },
};

const taskTwo: Task = {
  id: "get-age",
  // This should also be valid
  run: () => {
    return { age: 22 };
  },
};

const taskThree: Task = {
  id: "get-favourite-fruits",
  // This should fail with
  // Type '("apple" | "banana")[]' is not assignable to type
  // '("apple" | "strawberry" | "melon")[]'
  run: () => {
    return ["apple", "banana"];
  },
};
```

Comment: In your Task type, this should do the job `run: () => {age: number} | {name: string}; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `Task` to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) of the three different possible pairings of `id` and `run`.  You can generate this programmatically from `Outputs` by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) each property of `Outputs` to a value corresponding to this pairing, and then [looking up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) all of the mapped properties to get the desired union:

```
type Task = {
  [K in keyof Outputs]: { id: K, run: () => Outputs[K] }
}[keyof Outputs];

/* produces
type Task = {
    id: "get-name";
    run: () => {
        name: string;
    };
} | {
    id: "get-age";
    run: () => {
        age: number;
    };
} | {
    id: "get-favourite-fruits";
    run: () => ("apple" | "strawberry" | "melon")[];
}*/
```

Then the rest of your code works as desired.  Valid tasks are accepted:

```
const taskOne: Task = {
  id: "get-name",
  run: () => {
    return { name: "frankenstein" };
  },
}; // okay

const taskTwo: Task = {
  id: "get-age",
  run: () => {
    return { age: 22 };
  },
}; // okay
```

And invalid tasks are rejected:

```
const taskThree: Task = {
  id: "get-favourite-fruits",
  run: () => { // error!
    // Type '() => ("apple" | "banana")[]' is not assignable to type
    // '(() => { name: string; }) | (() => { age: number; }) | 
    // (() => ("apple" | "strawberry" | "melon")[])
    return ["apple", "banana"];
  },
};

const taskFour: Task = { // error!
//    ~~~~~~~~
// Type '{ id: "get-favourite-fruits"; run: () => { age: number; }; }'
// is not assignable to type 'Task'.
  id: "get-favourite-fruits",
  run: () => { 
    return { age: 123 };
  },
};
```

The errors for invalid tasks might be a bit different from the particular one you were expecting. For `taskThree` the compiler complains that `run()`'s return is incompatible with every possible `Task` member; "not only isn't it the right array, but it isn't even one of the right types for `get-name` or `get-age`!"  For `taskFour` the compiler sees that `run()` returns an `{age: number}` but the `id` is `get-favorite-fruits` and complains that the whole value is wrong without highlighting any particular property.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?esModuleInterop=false&target=2&jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA8grsMCDOUC8UDeAoKUBEA5hMALQB2AhgLYT4BcWueUVtjywATgJbmEBuZgF8heIiVKViDJiyjSIjcnGoAjCFzFRRzCWQBmlAG4B7OL2ARSBrnB7BksgBT5KYMABs6UAD4FOLkoAdw0uLhB8PwJaT1NyfABKAG0AXSFdbFBIKAAVSmQAa3Q5KGSAaSg+KEKIEFMDWAQkR1TGTCqAE0ZygBooO3JGZ0T0AD4mxBQK1J1sYWTa+sb4KdahbAB6ACos8Gh8opKceR5ugmIyNjptPEHh0bQJk-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-vuB5BgeAB0cqjipeKTlYGnEnOhbQiBHQUdq1EIVKACM1YAMz1mx8wCEAA)

Comment: I do want `Task` to be that! Expertly answered. It helped solve my problem and improved my understanding of Typescript. Thank you @jcalz

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by declaring a type which is either of them and based on the id the compiler can tell which one of those it is.

```
type GetNameTask = {
    id: "get-name";
    run: () => {name: string};
}
type GetAgeTask = {
    id: "get-age";
    run: () => {number: string};
}
type GetFavoriteFruitsTask = {
    id: "get-favourite-fruits"
    run: () => ("apple" | "strawberry" | "melon")[];
}

type Task = GetNameTask | GetAgeTask | GetFavoriteFruitsTask
```

For more a clean systax you can also try this:

```
type GenericTask<TId, TOutput> = {
    id: TId;
    run: () => TOutput
}

type GetNameTask2 = GenericTask<"get-name", {name: string}>
type GetAgeTask2 = GenericTask<"get-age", {age: number}>
type GetFavoriteFruitsTask2 = GenericTask<"get-favourite-fruits", ("apple" | "strawberry" | "melon")[]>
type Task = GetNameTask2 | GetAgeTask2 | GetFavoriteFruitsTask2
```